# Python: How can I execute bat file in new cmd window?

Tags: python, batch-file

In my python script:

```
p = Popen('a.bat')
```

The problem is that the output of the batch file is put to main console window in which I executed my python script... I want the output of the batch file to be shown in new console window. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the [`CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess#subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE) flag. For example:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('a.bat', creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

The docs regarding `shell=True` are inconsistent with the [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/70274d53c1dd/Lib/subprocess.py#l866). If you specify `shell=True`, it sets `CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE` only if the platform is either Win9x or uses the 16-bit `COMMAND.COM` shell.

Comment: This gives what I expected... Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used python before, so I can't test, but this should work

```
p = Popen('cmd.exe /k start a.bat')
```

Comment: Sorry, but this won't work. It needs set the creation flag to tell Win32's `CreateProcess` to create a new console for the process instead of inheriting the current console.